# Isomorphism of complete graphs preserving weighted edges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

This might be a simple question but unfortunately I do not know much about graph theory, and neither some simple induction-based approaches nor the Google search did return anything promising.

So, I have an undirected complete graph $G = (V_G, E_G)$ on $n \in \mathbb{N}$ vertices with weighted edges. Suppose that the weights take on values in the set $\{a_1, \ldots, a_k\}$ and, given a vertex $v \in V_G,$ denote by $n_{v,i}$ the number of edges $\{v,w\}$ with weigth $a_i.$ The special thing about $G$ is that the numbers $(n_{v,i})_{v \in V_G, i \in [k]}$ do not depend on $v,$ so we may denote them simply by $n_i.$

I also have another weighted graph $H = (V_H, E_H)$ on $n$ vertices with exactly the same properties, and the same numbers $n_i$.

Question: Is there alway a bijection $f: V_G \rightarrow V_H$ such that $f$ "preserves weigths", meaning that the weigth of $\{v,w\}$ is $a_i$ if and only if  the weigth of $\{f(v), f(w)\}$ is $a_i$?

Comment: No, that would be way too good from the point of view of graph isomorphism testing. In the special case when there are only two weights and you look at the subgraph induced by one of them then you are asking "is the isomorphism type of a $k$-regular graph on $n$ vertices determined by $n,k$?"  That is not true already for $n=6,k=2$.

Comment: Thank you very much!